# How do you add MKPolylines to MKSnapShotter in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, apple-maps, mkmapsnapshotter

Is there a way to take a screenshot of mapView and include the polyline? I believe I need to draw CGPoint's on the image that the MKSnapShotter returns, but I am unsure on how to do so.

**Current code**

```
      func takeSnapshot(mapView: MKMapView, withCallback: (UIImage?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
    options.region = mapView.region
    options.size = mapView.frame.size
    options.scale = UIScreen.main().scale

    let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)


    snapshotter.start() { snapshot, error in
        guard snapshot != nil else {
            withCallback(nil, error)
            return
        }

        if let image = snapshot?.image{



            withCallback(image, nil)

            for coordinate in self.area {

                image.draw(at:snapshot!.point(for: coordinate))

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In [Putting Map Kit in Perspective](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/309/) video, Apple demonstrates that if you want to include annotations in a snapshot, you have to manually draw them yourself. (Bewildering, yes, but it is what it is.) I assume the same is true for overlays such as the `MKPolyline`.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: Okay, so the video was informative, but didn't really help.

Comment: I would have thought that the demo, manually rendering the annotation pins in a snapshot, would have given you enough clues how to do the equivalent with overlays...

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem today. After several hours of research, here is how I solve it.

The following codes are in **Swift 3**.

#### 1. Init your polyline coordinates array

```
// initial this array with your polyline coordinates
var yourCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]() 
yourCoorinates.append( coordinate 1 )
yourCoorinates.append( coordinate 2 )
...
// you can use any data structure you like
```

#### 2. take the snapshot as usual, but set the region based on your coordinates:

```
func takeSnapShot() {
    let mapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions()

    // Set the region of the map that is rendered. (by polyline)
    let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &yourCoordinates, count: yourCoordinates.count)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polyLine.boundingMapRect)

    mapSnapshotOptions.region = region

    // Set the scale of the image. We'll just use the scale of the current device, which is 2x scale on Retina screens.
    mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale

    // Set the size of the image output.
    mapSnapshotOptions.size = CGSize(width: IMAGE_VIEW_WIDTH, height: IMAGE_VIEW_HEIGHT)

    // Show buildings and Points of Interest on the snapshot
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsBuildings = true
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    let snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)

    snapShotter.start() { snapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            return
        }
        // Don't just pass snapshot.image, pass snapshot itself!
        self.imageView.image = self.drawLineOnImage(snapshot: snapshot)
    }
}
```

#### 3. Use snapshot.point() to draw Polylines on Snapshot Image

```
func drawLineOnImage(snapshot: MKMapSnapshot) -> UIImage {
    let image = snapshot.image

    // for Retina screen
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, true, 0)

    // draw original image into the context
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // set stroking width and color of the context
    context!.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.orange.cgColor)

    // Here is the trick :
    // We use addLine() and move() to draw the line, this should be easy to understand.
    // The diificult part is that they both take CGPoint as parameters, and it would be way too complex for us to calculate by ourselves
    // Thus we use snapshot.point() to save the pain.
    context!.move(to: snapshot.point(for: yourCoordinates[0]))
    for i in 0...yourCoordinates.count-1 {
      context!.addLine(to: snapshot.point(for: yourCoordinates[i]))
      context!.move(to: snapshot.point(for: yourCoordinates[i]))
    }

    // apply the stroke to the context
    context!.strokePath()

    // get the image from the graphics context
    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // end the graphics context 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage!
}
```

That's it, hope this helps someone.

#### References

- [How do I draw on an image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950125/how-do-i-draw-on-an-image-in-swift/41858846#41858846)
- [MKTile​Overlay,MKMap​Snapshotter & MKDirections](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/)
- [Creating an MKMapSnapshotter with an MKPolylineRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692449/creating-an-mkmapsnapshotter-with-an-mkpolylinerenderer)
- [Render a Map as an Image using MapKit](https://dispatchswift.com/render-a-map-as-an-image-using-mapkit-3102a5a3fa5#.fbn0lgdl1)

Comment: @user287589 How to calculate region span to have insets on snapshot?

Comment: @AymenHARRATH I don't know. Sorry

Comment: I tried running this snippet of code. It gives me following error in this line: context!.setLineWidth(2.0)
Error message says: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
snapshotter.start( completionHandler: { snapshot, error in
  guard snapshot != nil else {
    withCallback(nil, error)
    return
  }

  if let image = snapshot?.image {
    withCallback(image, nil)

    for coordinate in self.area {
      image.draw(at:snapshot!.point(for: coordinate))
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: I ended up just storing the coordinates in an array, then displaying them on a Map I created in another view.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a copy of the image the user sees in the MKMapView, remember that it's a UIView subclass, and so you could do this...

```
public extension UIView {
    public var snapshot: UIImage? {
        get {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image
        }
    }
}

// ...
if let img = self.mapView.snapshot {
    // Do something
}
```